# Restrict scope of variable within include file in php

Tags: php

I am facing variable conflicting issues in application i am designing.

e.g in one of my web application page, there are two modules

i: tag clouds module
ii: photo listing module

both have variable **$listOrder** , e.g when script processing module "**tag cloudes**" it set **$listOrder = "tagid desc"** as its not set initially.

```
if(!isset($listOrder))
   $listOrder = "tagid desc";
```

When script reach to photo listing module again it try to process the following line as shown above. as variable is already set in tag cloud list. it keeps "tagid desc" as value. which causes sql error as "tagid" is not a field of photo listing.

This is simple example there are more than 4 or 5 modules with lots of similar variables in every page, which cause conflicts.

Can we do something to restrict scope of variable to module level in php to avoid such conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can classes and (starting from PHP 5.3) namespaces.

If you have a class like this, you can put variables and functions in that class:

```
class Module1
{
  public $listOrder = 'tagid desc';

  public function generateSQL()
  {
    return 'select * from YourTable order by ' . $this->listOrder;
  }
}
```

Now you can make an instance of a module (you could even create multiple instances), and call its methods:

```
$module1 = new Module1;
$module1->listOrder = 'name asc'; // Override default sorting
$sql = $module1->generateSQL();
```

This is only a small example of the possibilities, but I think a complete tutorial on classes/oop would be out of order here. ;)

Comment: in classes it can be restricted, but i faces problem in include files, responsible for getting values either directly or through ajax params. these values then passed further to classes to generate appropriate outputs.

Comment: alternatively if i unset all variables which is set within module scope may solve my issue.

Comment: Include files can contain classes too. You should put as little as possible in the global scope.